# Stale Element Reference Exception problem

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, staleelementreferenceexception

so i 'm trying with this code to retrieve some informations (Inchikey and SMILES) from lipids database but my code crash after the first itteration with this error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)

in <cell line: 35>()
35 for row in rows:
36     # Get the elements of each row
---> 37     cells = row.find_elements('tag name', 'td')
38
39     # Check if the row contains enough cells

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
243                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def web_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--verbose")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Create an instance of the WebDriver using the configured browser options
driver = web_driver()

# Open the website URL in the browser
url = 'https://www.swisslipids.org/#/browse_tree?entity_id=SLM:000389800'
driver.get(url)

# Interact with the elements on the page to extract the desired data
# Find the table element
table_element = driver.find_element('css selector', '.table')

# Iterate through the table rows, excluding the first header row
rows = table_element.find_elements('tag name', 'tr')[1:]

count = 0  # Counter initialized to 0

for row in rows:
    # Get the elements of each row
    cells = row.find_elements('tag name', 'td')

    # Check if the row contains enough cells
    if len(cells) >= 2:
        # Extract the data from each cell
        identifiant_lipid = cells[0].text.strip()
        lipid_name = cells[1].text.strip()

        # Generate the specific link for each lipid ID by combining it with the base URL
        lipid_link = f'https://www.swisslipids.org/#/entity/{identifiant_lipid}/'

        count += 1  # Increment the counter

        print("ID lipid:", identifiant_lipid)
        print("Nom lipide:", lipid_name)
        print("Lien:", lipid_link)

        # Open the specific link for each lipid ID
        driver.get(lipid_link)

        time.sleep(1)  # Pause for page load

        try:
            # Explicitly wait for the chemInfo element to be clickable
            chem_info_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#chemInfo > fieldset:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)'))
            )

            # Find all the dt and dd elements within the chemInfo element
            dt_elements = chem_info_element.find_elements('tag name', 'dt')
            dd_elements = chem_info_element.find_elements('tag name', 'dd')

            # Extract the desired information based on the index of the dt element
            for index, dt_element in enumerate(dt_elements):
                dt_text = dt_element.text.strip()
                dd_element = dd_elements[index]

                if dt_text == 'InChI key':
                    inchi_key = dd_element.text.strip().replace('InChIKey=', '')
                    print("InChI Key:", inchi_key)

                if dt_text == 'SMILES':
                    smiles = dd_element.text.strip()
                    print("SMILES:", smiles)

        except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException) as e:
            print("Informations chimiques non trouvées")
            print("Exception:", e)

        print()  # Empty line for better readability

# Print the total number of lipid IDs
print("Nombre total d'ID lipid:", count)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Ps: Actually, it does print the right answer but just for the first itteration and then crash;

Here is the print for the first itteration:

ID lipid: SLM:000000510
Nom lipide: hexadecanoate
Lien: https://www.swisslipids.org/#/entity/SLM:000000510/
InChI Key: IPCSVZSSVZVIGE-UHFFFAOYSA-M
SMILES: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC([O-])=O

Thanks in advance

i try every kind of code i saw here, and what i want is to be able to retrieve InChI Key and
SMILES informations for each lipid_link.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that code tries traversing through each row element whereas changing that page in between, rendering the row element stale (since the page got changed, it can't be located anymore)

```
# Iterate through the table rows, excluding the first header row
rows = table_element.find_elements('tag name', 'tr')[1:]

count = 0  # Counter initialized to 0

for row in rows:
    # Get the elements of each row
    cells = row.find_elements('tag name', 'td')

    # Open the specific link for each lipid ID
    driver.get(lipid_link)
```

This is the basic flow of your code. As you can see here, you are accessing rows from the initial page, then in each row, you're changing the current page of Webdriver.

The solution will be to parse and store row details in memory rather than accessing them in real-time.

I have tweaked the code a bit for parsing the rows using beautiful soup and it is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def web_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--verbose")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    return webdriver.Chrome(service= Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

# Create an instance of the WebDriver using the configured browser options
driver = web_driver()

# Open the website URL in the browser
url = 'https://www.swisslipids.org/#/browse_tree?entity_id=SLM:000389800'
driver.get(url)

# Interact with the elements on the page to extract the desired data
# Find the table element
table_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table')))

# Iterate through the table rows, excluding the first header row
rows = bs(table_element.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml').find_all('tr')[1:]

count = 0  # Counter initialized to 0

for row in rows:
    # Get the elements of each row
    cells = row.find_all('td')

    # Check if the row contains enough cells
    if len(cells) >= 2:
        # Extract the data from each cell
        identifiant_lipid = cells[0].text.strip()
        lipid_name = cells[1].text.strip()

        # Generate the specific link for each lipid ID by combining it with the base URL
        lipid_link = f'https://www.swisslipids.org/#/entity/{identifiant_lipid}/'

        count += 1  # Increment the counter

        print("ID lipid:", identifiant_lipid)
        print("Nom lipide:", lipid_name)
        print("Lien:", lipid_link)

        # Open the specific link for each lipid ID
        driver.get(lipid_link)

        try:
            # Explicitly wait for the chemInfo element to be clickable
            chem_info_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#chemInfo > fieldset:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)'))
            )

            # Find all the dt and dd elements within the chemInfo element
            dt_elements = chem_info_element.find_elements('tag name', 'dt')
            dd_elements = chem_info_element.find_elements('tag name', 'dd')

            # Extract the desired information based on the index of the dt element
            for index, dt_element in enumerate(dt_elements):
                dt_text = dt_element.text.strip()
                dd_element = dd_elements[index]

                if dt_text == 'InChI key':
                    inchi_key = dd_element.text.strip().replace('InChIKey=', '')
                    print("InChI Key:", inchi_key)

                if dt_text == 'SMILES':
                    smiles = dd_element.text.strip()
                    print("SMILES:", smiles)

        except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException) as e:
            print("Informations chimiques non trouvées")
            print("Exception:", e)

        print()  # Empty line for better readability

# Print the total number of lipid IDs
print("Nombre total d'ID lipid:", count)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

And output was fine, here's the partial output

```
ID lipid: SLM:000000510
Nom lipide: hexadecanoate
Lien: https://www.swisslipids.org/#/entity/SLM:000000510/
InChI Key: IPCSVZSSVZVIGE-UHFFFAOYSA-M
SMILES: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC([O-])=O

ID lipid: SLM:000000719
Nom lipide: dodecanoate
Lien: https://www.swisslipids.org/#/entity/SLM:000000719/
InChI Key: IPCSVZSSVZVIGE-UHFFFAOYSA-M
SMILES: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC([O-])=O
```

Comment: I used webdriver-manager to avoid installing ChromeDriver. That is an optional step and you can skip it.